# Java: Compile inter-related classes

Tags: java, compiler-construction, dependencies

Say I have: `class A` depends on `class B` depends on `class C` depends on `class A`.

It seems impossible to compile. I have read [this post about disabling compile-time depedency-checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537714/disabling-compile-time-dependency-checking-when-compiling-java-classes), but all my classes are within the classpath, well-defined, etc. The only problem is that they mutually depend on each other.

Is there a way to write such an application that would compile without a hitch?

Comment: this is not necessarily and answer, but i have to ask -- how did you start writing that code? did you write class A first? or class B? or class C? chicken/egg? :)

Comment: When you say "it seems impossible to compile": have you tried it? It should just work.

Comment: well, `javac *.java` errors out.

Comment: OK. Seems I had a problem with a constructor. Now, what answer do I choose...?

Comment: (for the sake of it) @Liv: all at the same time; no chicken nor egg. @Peter & @Paulo: Thanks for the details.

Comment: @CiroSantilli This is a 4 years old question with an accepted answer, and the comments clearly show that my problem was unrelated (something about a constructor). Your comment is completely unrealistic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We do have several such dependency cycles in our legacy codebase and they do compile without a hitch.

This is not to say it is good to have cyclic dependencies - on the contrary. I intend to get rid of them eventually to clean up our architecture. Nevertheless, in the meantime, the code still compiles and works.

Comment: how do you write them then? Is there a way of referring to classes that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @passcod, class A has a property of type B, B a property of type C and C a property of type A. What kind of dependencies do you have?

Answer (score 1):

The important thing here is that the compiler must be able to compile all the classes at the same time. If this is the case, there should be no problem. Of course, you should take care of the usual directory layout problems.

If the packages can't be compiled together, it gets more complicated - you might have to create dummy implementations first (which don't depend on the other classes) and then (when you have the right classes) substitute them. But I can't really imagine an reason for not being able to compile them together.

Answer (score 0):

You can have this circular dependancy like this as Java knows which files to read to find the code from the name. i.e. it compiles them all at once.  You will only have a problem if you try to compile one at a time.